# Which node version is good for upgrade from version 16?

Tags: node.js, mongodb-atlas

I have a node application on engine 16 and I’m struggling whether to go for Node 18 or Node 20? All it does is Crud operations in Mongo. I read everywhere that Node 18 is the LTS version but if I wanna do an upgrade, should I go directly to 20? I use mocha and chai for test cases. Can someone guide me what’s a good direction for an enterprise application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node 18 is probably better because it will be supported for longer, and you're less likely to run into bugs if you use 20. Not many libraries require Node 20 to be used.

But, it might be good to try both since you can always upgrade and downgrade versions at any time.

Comment: Right, I agree. But I wanted to understand what’s the disadvantages of using a non stable version? Is there anything specific I need to keep in mind? Apart from some packages not compatible with it? And before that how do I find if it’s compatible or not?